# How to fix C++ error: expected unqualified-id

Tags: c++

I'm getting this error on line 6:

> ```
> error: expected unqualified-id before '{' token
> ```

I can't tell what's wrong.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class WordGame;
{               // <== error is here on line 6
public:

    void setWord( string word )
    {
        theWord = word;
    }
    string getWord()
    {
        return theWord;
    }
    void displayWord()
    {
        cout << "Your word is " << getWord() << endl;
    }
private:
    string theWord;
}


int main()
{
    string aWord;
    WordGame theGame;
    cin >> aWord;
    theGame.setWord(aWord);
    theGame.displaymessage();

}
```

Comment: Bizarrely someone has just copy-pasted this Q&A to a YouTube video: https://youtu.be/lMZpXWJbcn8

Answer (score 43, accepted):

There should be no semicolon here:

```
class WordGame;
```

...but there should be one at the end of your class definition:

```
...
private:
    string theWord;
}; // <-- Semicolon should be at the end of your class definition
```

Answer (score 9):

As a side note, consider passing strings in setWord() as const references to avoid excess copying.  Also, in displayWord, consider making this a const function to follow const-correctness.

```
void setWord(const std::string& word) {
  theWord = word;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Get rid of the semicolon after `WordGame`.

You really should have discovered this problem when the class was a lot smaller. When you're writing code, you should be compiling about every time you add half a dozen lines.

Answer (score 3):

Semicolon should be at the end of the class definition rather than after the name:

```
class WordGame
{
};
```

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, I had the same problem but it wasn't because of an **extra** semicolon, it was because I'd forgotten a semicolon on the previous statement.

My situation was something like

```
mynamespace::MyObject otherObject

for (const auto& element: otherObject.myVector) {
  // execute arbitrary code on element
  //...
  //...
}
```

From this code, my compiler kept telling me:

`error: expected unqualified-id before for (const auto& element: otherObject.myVector) {
etc...`

which I'd taken to mean I'd writtten the for loop wrong. Nope! I'd simply forgotten a `;` after declaring `otherObject`.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with this situation: I saw this error when I accidentally used `my_first_scope::my_second_scope::true` in place of simply `true`, like this:

```
bool my_var = my_first_scope::my_second_scope::true;
```

instead of:

```
bool my_var = true;
```

This is because I had a macro which caused `MY_MACRO(true)` to expand into `my_first_scope::my_second_scope::true`, by mistake, and I was actually calling `bool my_var = MY_MACRO(true);`.

Here's a quick demo of this type of scoping error:

Program (you can run it online here: https://onlinegdb.com/BkhFBoqUw):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

namespace my_first_scope 
{
namespace my_second_scope
{
} // namespace my_second_scope
} // namespace my_first_scope

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
    
    bool my_var = my_first_scope::my_second_scope::true;
    
    std::cout << my_var << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output (build error):

> ```
> main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
> main.cpp:27:52: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘true’
>      bool my_var = my_first_scope::my_second_scope::true;
>                                                     ^~~~
> ```

Notice the error: `error: expected unqualified-id before ‘true’`, and where the arrow under the error is pointing. **Apparently the *"unqualified-id"* in my case is the double colon (`::`) scope operator I have just before `true`.**

When I add in the macro and use it (run this new code here: https://onlinegdb.com/H1eevs58D):

```
#define MY_MACRO(input) my_first_scope::my_second_scope::input

...

bool my_var = MY_MACRO(true);
```

I get this new error instead:

> ```
> main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
> main.cpp:29:28: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘true’
>      bool my_var = MY_MACRO(true);
>                             ^
> main.cpp:16:58: note: in definition of macro ‘MY_MACRO’
>  #define MY_MACRO(input) my_first_scope::my_second_scope::input
>                                                           ^~~~~
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because I was not declaring a variable and was using it further .
Here is my code why I was getting it.

> It was because I was not declaring a variable for size of my >vector.
> Just replace

```
int n=arr.size();
```

Replace Here,

```
int sumSubarrayMins(vector<int>& arr) {
        
        
        int = arr.size();
        long long sum;
        long long ans =0;
        for(long i =0;i<n;i++){
            
             sum =0;
            long mini=INT_MAX;
            for(long long j =i;j<n;j++){
                mini=min(mini,arr[j]);
                sum+=mini;
            }
            ans+=sum;
           

        }
        return ans;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you forget this   void setWord( string word )

Comment: you forget this 
 void setWord( string word ); <=