# My code keeps on throwing the error expected unqualified-id. I want to know why?

Tags: c++, templates

This error occurs in the merged items do not fit within list in the while statement conditions.I can't figure out what is up with the code. Everything is declared correctly. All of the if statements within the while loop have the error unexpected unqualified id.

```
#include "OrderedList.h"
using namespace std;

template < typename DataType, typename KeyType >
OrderedList<DataType, KeyType>:: OrderedList ( int maxNumber )

:List<DataType>(maxNumber)

{}

template < typename DataType, typename KeyType >
void OrderedList::<DataType,KeyType>:: insert ( const DataType &newDataItem)
throw ( logic_error)

{
    if (size >= maxSize)
        throw logic_error("list is full fool");

    if (binarySearch(newDataItem.getKey(), cursor))
            dataItem[cursor] = newDataItem;

    else
    {
        for ( int j= size-1 ; j > cursor; --j)
            dataItems[j+1] = dataitems[j];
            ++cursor;
        dataItems[cursor] = newDataItem;
        ++size;
    }
}

template < typename DataType, typename KeyType >
bool OrderedList< DataType, KeyType> :: retrieve ( const KeyType& searchKey, DataType &searchDataItem)

{
    int holdCursor = cursor;

    bool result = false;

if (binarySearch(searchKey, cursor))
{
    searchDataItem = dataItems[cursor];
    result = true;
}
else
{
    cursor = holdCursor;
    result = false;
}
    return result;
}

template < typename DataType, typename KeyType >
void OrderedList<DataType, KeyType>:: replace ( const DataType &newDataItem)
throw (logic_error)

{
    if (size==0)
        throw logic_error("listEmpty");

    if (newDataItem.getKey() == dataItems[cursor].getKey() )
        dataItems[cursor] = newDataItem;
        else
        {
            remove();
            insert(newDataItem);
        }
}


template < typename DataType, typename KeyType > void OrderedList<DataType, KeyType>:: showStructure () const

{
    if (size == 0)
        cout << "Empty List" << endl;
    else
    {
        cout << "size = " << size
        << "  cursor = " << cursor << endl;
        for ( int j = 0 ; j < maxSize ; ++j)
            cout << endl;
        for (int j = 0; j < size ; ++j)
        {
            if( j == cursor)
            {
                cout << "[" << dataItems[j].getKey() << "]\t";
            }
            else {
                cout << dataItems[j].getKey() << "\t";
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}


template < typename DataType, typename KeyType >
bool OrderedList < DataType, KeyType >:: binarySearch (KeyType searchKey, int &index)

{
    int low = 0
    high = size - 1;
    bool result;

    while (low <= high)
    {
        index = (low + high ) / 2;
        if ( searchKey < dataItems[index].getKey())
            high = index - 1;
        else if( searchKey > dataItems[index].getKey())
            low = index + 1;
        else
            break;
    }
    if ( low <= high )
        result = true;
    else
    {
        index = high;
        result = false;
    }
    return result;
}

template < typename DataType, typename KeyType>
void OrderedList< DataType, KeyType>:: merge ( const OrderedList<DataType, KeyType>& fromL )
throw (logic_error)

{
    int j = size - 1,
        k = fromL.size - 1,
        m = size + fromL.size - 1;

}

if ( size + fromL.size > maxSize)
throw logic_error("merged items do not fit within list");

while (( j >= 0 ) && (k >= 0))
    if ( fromL.dataItems[k].getKey() == dataItems[j].getKey())
throw logic_error("lists are supposed to have no common keys");
else if ( fromL.dataitems[k].getKey() > dataItems[j].getKey())
dataItems[m--] = fromL.dataItems[k--];
else dataItems[m--] = dataItems[j--];

for ( m = k ; m >= 0 ; m--)
dataItems[m]= fromL.dataItems[m];

size += fromL.size;

if (size != 0 )
cursor = 0;



template < typename DataType, typename KeyType >
bool OrderedList < DataType, KeyType> :: isSubset (const OrderedList <DataType, KeyType> &subList)

{
    int j = 0,
    k = 0;
    bool result = false;

    while (( j < size) && (k < subList.size))
    {
        if ( dataItems[j]. getKey() < subList.dataItems[k].getKey())
            j++;
        else if (dataItems[j]. getKey() == subList.dataItems[k].getKey())
        {
            j++;
            k++;
        }
        else
            result = false;
}

if (k == subList.size)
    result = true;

else
    result= false;

    return result;

}

//#endif
```

Comment: where is size declared?

Comment: I declared it and it didn't change the errors at all

Comment: Post the exact error message including line numbers please. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10135244/c-error-expected-unqualified-id