# Xcode: Expected unqualified-id

Tags: c++, xcode

I receive: Expected unqualified-id with

```
constexpr inline double M_PI = 3.14159265358979323846;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide [mre]. I [cannot reproduce](https://wandbox.org/permlink/5bJNimGSKPk7AVxm) the issue with code given.

Comment: Maybe see if this helps?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10135244/c-error-expected-unqualified-id

Comment: Try removing the `inline` keyword.  I really don't know how to inline a constant, or if that makes sense.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with an *inline* constant?  Most constants are either placed into the executable code (text) section or they are placed into a read-only section.

Comment: Usually, the `inline` keyword is applied to functions, not variables.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews it's C++17 feature, inline const and vars can be defined in multiple translation units (in .h without `extern` for example).

Comment: You are probably including a file that `#define`s `M_PI` and now the declaration doesn't make any sense anymore. Please show a full [repro] and the compiler invocation used to compile it.

Comment: For your [mcve], it should be enough to `#include <cmath>` then define your constant. However, since that is conjecture on my part, I'll leave it up to you to verify (or come with a different example if your situation is different) and update your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a compiler/header bug that allows `M_PI` to be defined (as a macro) under some circumstances; see [bug #1810695](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glibc/+bug/1810695). The bug is not yours since `M_PI` is not a reserved identifier, hence `M_PI` should be available for you to use as a variable name. You can work around this by making sure `M_PI` is not a macro when you define your version.

```
#undef M_PI
constexpr inline double M_PI = 3.14159265358979323846;
```

As long as the value of your constant matches the value generated by the macro, there should not be an issue. Still, be aware that when you use `M_PI`, if you forget to `#include` your header, you might end up using the macro instead of your (C++-style) constant.

(For those trying to parse the error message, clang provides a more illustrative error message than gcc. After macro expansion, the attempted declaration had become `constexpr inline double 3.14159265358979323846 = 3.14159265358979323846;`, and that first numeric literal is not an unqualified-id.)